# .NET NLog retreive local directory

Tags: nlog

The following retrieves the temp directory :

`${tempdir}`

How do I retrieve the local directory ?

I am talking about the configuration file used to setup the log
environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for one of these:

- [${BaseDir}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Basedir-layout-renderer)
- [${CurrentDir}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CurrentDir-Layout-Renderer)
- [${ProcessDir}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessDir-Layout-Renderer)
- [${AspNet-AppBasePath}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-AppBasePath-layout-renderer)